# Counter when 2 values are most frequent

Tags: python, list, frequency

For example, I got a list of lists with two values which are tied in being the most frequent.
Lines = the list of lists,  I used:

```
from collections import Counter
most_freq = Counter(bin for sublist in lines for bin in sublist).most_common(1)[0][0]
```

Iterating over the list, it prints only one result (I understand that's because of the 1)..
I found recently in the forum the following code:

```
counts = collections.Counter(lines)
mostCommon = counts.most_common()
print(mostCommon)
```

But the error is "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"
What should I change to print all most frequent values available?

Comment: Your lists elements are lists and they cannot be used as keys in order for `Counter` to generate the dictionary. You could change your lists to `tuples` so that `Counter` accepts them as keys. Could you post an example of a `lines` list?

Comment: [['VPS', 'TR'], ['VPS', 'PR'], ['VPS', 'HD'], ['VPS', 'ARI'], ['VPS', 'DBS], ....[ZEB,LOA], [ZEB,MON]]    total of 32659

Comment: I prefer not changing to tuples, I have to do other functions as well and it's iterating over 7000+ files in total (that's why I choose Counter func).

Comment: What is the output you want, specifically? The strings or the lists?

Comment: I need the strings, to save the most frequent --> after that I do some changes and searching the most frequent strings again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prints a list of the two most common items in the sublists:

```
from collections import Counter
most_common = Counter(item for sublist in lines for item in sublist).most_common(2)
print([item for item, _ in most_common])
```

After your comment, I think you are looking for the multimode:

```
from statistics import multimode
print(multimode(item for sublist in lines for item in sublist))
```

Comment: Thanks but I need only the first in case there is only one

Comment: Thank you! , very useful. I found another way with a loop but this one is much better

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method from the `list`, in order to find the total occurences of each sublist and then use the [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#max) function to find the most frequent one:

```
most_common = max(lines, key=lambda e: lines.count(e))
```

Comment: It didn't work, gave a list as an answer and a wrong one

Comment: @TheUndecided what is the format of the expected output? What do you expect, if it's not a list?

Comment: I expect to get the most frequent value. If I have "ZEB" as the most frequent, I don't expect to get "[ZEB,AGH4]", just ZEB. In case I got ZEB and DO2H as the most frequent, I expect to get both

Comment: In this case, you'll have to unpack all values in one list and then use `Counter`. That will work.

Comment: I can do it, the problem is that I will have to pack them again for the next actions.. and it's lots of files, is there any "lighter" way?

Comment: You can create a dictionary with these strings as key and manually keeps track the number of times they appear.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understood the idea. I got lots of files and in each file I find the most frequent string, and delete all these who connects it in a list. After that I repeat that action (and these who are in the same list, must be deleted)

Comment: Forget about the dictionary, you're going to need to use another list to store all your values without sublists and find the most frequent one. There is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Possible adding:

```
most = Counter(b for sublist in lines for b in sublist).most_common(1)[0][0] # most freq'
all_freq = Counter(g for sublist in lines for g in sublist).most_common() 
# prints all frequencies
how_many_times_most_appears = Counter(b for sublist in lines for b in sublist).most_common(1)[0][1] # The most frequent
for k in all_freq:
    if k[1] == how_many_times_most_appears:
        print(k)
 
 # finding which value is same as the most
```