# Fixing code when printing frequent values, python

Tags: python, list, loops, frequency

Related to [Counter when 2 values are most frequent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64091477/counter-when-2-values-are-most-frequent)

I made a demo list for the example,
Running it with "for i in range (len(lines))":

```
from statistics import multimode
lines = [[0,1],[1,5],[1,3],[67,45],[98,23],[67,68],[23,2],[1,18],[23,67],[40,79],[40,234],[40,41],[41,51]]

most = multimode(item for sublist in lines for item in sublist)
for a in most:
    del_connected = [bin for bin in lines if a in bin] # these connected to the maximum occured 
    for i, k in del_connected:
        lines = [x for x in lines if k not in x]
        lines = [x for x in lines if i not in x]
print(lines)
```

First round, there is only one occurred value "1", but in the second round there are 3: 41,23,67. That's why I did a for loop and matched "most" to "a" but del_connected prints the wrong values and so the "lines" list itself -->

```
>>[[67, 45], [67, 68], [23, 67]]
>>[]
>>[[40, 79], [40, 234], [40, 41]]
```

How do I fix it's print when there are more than one frequent value?

Comment: I think you shouldn't do that `most = a`? Why don't you do just `del_connected = [bin for bin in lines if a in bin]`?

Comment: Possible, but gives the same results , I will edit that in the question **

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't now how `most` looks like, since `multimode` is not available in your sample.

Comment: In this loop `for i, k in del_connected:` you do 2 assignments to `lines`: Is that intended (the first one gets overwritten)?

Comment: @Timus `multimode` is [`statistics.multimode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.multimode) which is new in Python 3.8

Comment: Most prints the most prequent value ,in the first round it's "[1]". I add "i" and "k" because there are two values in each list and they both are relevant. Added input.

Comment: I still trying to understand what youre trying to do. For a pair a, b in find the order they by frequence or what?

Comment: I iterate through the code I posted, it always prints the most occurred value and then it deletes all the values which were connected to him in the list (to be done, need to save the most frequent..) and it repeats itself till the last list. The problem occurr when there are more than one most frequent occurrence as I showed

Comment: Order or the frequency itself doesn't play a role, the frequency is just for filtering the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this:

```
lines = ...

while len(lines) > 0:
    print(lines)
    most = multimode(item for sublist in lines for item in sublist)
    connected = [
        bin
        for bin in lines
        for a in most
        if a in bin
    ]
    for i, k in connected:
        lines = [
            bin
            for bin in lines
            if (i not in bin) or (k not in bin)
        ]
```

Comment: Absolutely, thanks, I am quite confused about what did I do wrong? * editing, I guess that I will still need to use my code to find which value is most frequent and staying in each round

Comment: @TheUndecided You did loop only over the first results from `most`. I.e. there were no next rounds with adjusted `lines`.